# iTextPdf not loading Images correctly

Tags: java, pdf, itext, jpeg

Heyo, i have a problem with this piece of code:

```
  private void createPDF(String[] url, String name) throws FileNotFoundException, DocumentException, IOException{
    com.itextpdf.text.Document document = new com.itextpdf.text.Document();
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(name);
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, fos);
    writer.open();
    document.open();
    document.setMargins(1, 0, 0, 0);
    document.addTitle(name);
    document.addSubject(name);
    for (String url1 : url) {
      Image i = Image.getInstance(new java.net.URL(url1));
      i.scaleToFit(document.getPageSize());
      document.add(i);
      document.newPage();
      writer.flush();
    }
    document.close();
    writer.close();
  }
```

The Images are jpeg formatted and on a server an I am using iText-pdfa-5.5.5 with iText-xtra-5.5.5 via Maven.

The Problem is, that some pictures are not displayed correctly but like cut in halve. How can I prevent this to happen?

What I tried until now:

- what you see above
- preloading the image with ImageIO

both with the same result.

Please help me.

---

okay i just inserted (with getImage beeing from Bruno Lowagies code below)

```
  BufferedImage read = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(getImage(new java.net.URL(url1))));
  ImageIO.write(read, "jpeg", new File(url1.substring(url1.length()-8, url1.length())));
  Image i = Image.getInstance(read, null);
```

and the Files I get arent fully downloaded and the bottom part of the picture seems to be filled with #808080

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iText doesn't change a singe byte of a JPG image. It just takes the bytes it receives and puts them inside the PDF in a stream defining the `/Filter` as `/DCTDecode`, so there should be no problem importing JPG images.

However, looking at your code, I see that you expect the `Image` object to load the file from an URL: `new java.net.URL(url1)` and I remember people having problems similar to yours because the `InputStream` obtained from the `URL` object wasn't always fully read when `url1` wasn't a file URL, but an URL to some image on the web.

This problem was inherent to reading `InputStream`s: the `Image` needs to read the first bytes of the `InputStream` first to determine the image type, and then go back to the start of the `InputStream` to read the full image.

To work around this problem, it is better to read the image into a `byte[]` first and to use this `byte[]` as a parameter for the `Image` constructor.

Something like this:

```
public byte[] getImage(URL url) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    InputStream is = url.openStream ();
    byte[] b = new byte[4096];
    int n;
    while ( (n = is.read(b)) > -1 ) {
        baos.write(b, 0, n);
    }
    return baos.toByteArray();
}
```

And then:

```
Image i = Image.getInstance(getImage(new java.net.URL(url1)));
```

I wrote these code snippets without testing. Please let me know if they work (or update my answer if I made some typos).

Comment: what should byteChunk be? b?

Comment: Correct, that was indeed a typo. (I always seem to make at least one when I write code off the cuff.)

Comment: joa typos happen :-P but that doesn't solve the problem. I still get cut pictures...

Comment: What if you save the downloaded images as JPGs? Are they fully downloaded? I've seen this behavior occur due to network problem. By saving the `byte[]` as a JPG file you can either rule out iText as the culprit (if those images are incomplete) or determine that it is an iText problem (in which case, we'll try to find out what happens if we load the images into a PDF from a file).

Comment: the files don't get downloaded correctly, see my edit to the question

Comment: I finally found the bug in your code: n = is.read(b)) > 0. It should be >=, because 0 means we got nothing but there may be more to come. Only -1 is the end of the file. Now it loads the complete images.

Comment: @MiSt Thank you for fixing this; I've updated my answer.